# How to add reference from Internet for visual studio 2013 in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, reference

I can not  run a project that built in another laptop with same version of visual studio.There is an error

```
"Error  4   The type or namespace name 'Ivi' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

How I add this to my laptop visual studio

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FSuE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler tells you, that you are missing some references. Most likely you are missing some assemblies.
Check under References if both assemblies are available. Do they have an yellow warning sign? If yes, visual studio can not resolve the path to the assembly or the assembly is just missing.

You have to provide some more details about your setup or configuration of the project to determine the situation.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.yes there are yellow warning signs.how i solve this problem.is there any way to download or add this missing reference?

Comment: You have to get the assembly on your second laptop. When you know how [nuget](https://www.nuget.org) works, you can try to get your assemblies there. The other way: right click on references and click add references...now you have to find both and add them, so the path to these assemblies will be updated.

Comment: Furthermore can you say how i install this reference from nuget.thank you

Comment: I try to search online these reference but I could not do that.please give me a help

Comment: I had a quick look: 
[Information about the agilent assembly](http://www.keysight.com/upload/cmc_upload/All/visacom.html?&cc=DE)
[Information about the IVI.Driver assembly](http://de.tek.com/support/faqs/how-can-i-add-reference-ivi-com-driver-c-or-vbnet)